# Looping Through a List and a List of Lists in Parallel (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a function that takes 2 parameters; the first one is a list of strings while the second parameter is a list of lists of strings. The aim of the function is to take nth index of the first parameter and creates a dictionary that assigns the nth index of the first parameter as the key, and assigns it to a value that is the matching index in the 2nd parameter. For example:

The function call:
`list_dic_gen(['One','Two'], [['First','Second']])`

Would result in the output: `[{'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}]`

The function call:
`list_dic_gen(['Second'], [['One'],['Third Fourth']])`

Would result in the output:
`[{'Second': 'One'}, {'Second': 'Third Fourth'}]`

I was wondering what would the best way to approach this problem be.

Comment: The question states to assume that the length of the first parameter is equal to each list in the 2nd parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` while iterating along each sublist.

```
def list_dic_gen(l1, l2):
    res = []
    for l in l2:
        res.append(dict(zip(l1, l)))
    return res

examples = (['One','Two'], [['First','Second']]), (['Second'], [['One'],['Third Fourth']])
for l1, l2 in examples:
    o = list_dic_gen(l1, l2)
    print(o)

#[{'One': 'First', 'Two': 'Second'}]
#[{'Second': 'One'}, {'Second': 'Third Fourth'}]
```

or with a list comprehension

```
def list_dic_gen(l1, l2):
    return [dict(zip(l1, l)) for l in l2]
```